# How to parallelize the dataframe transformation using pyspark pipeline?

Tags: python, hadoop, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My approach is as below. I think as I am using for loop and treating each column separately, this code in not distribute as it takes many hours to finish.
I have 8000 columns in pyspark dataframe. Can you please tell me a proper way to implement this in parallelize/distributed way. Thanks

```
indexers = [ 
 StringIndexer(inputCol=c, outputCol="{}_idx".format(c)) for c in cat_string]

encoders1 = [
  OneHotEncoder(
    inputCol=idx.getOutputCol(),
    outputCol="{0}_enc".format(idx.getOutputCol())) for idx in indexers]

encoders2 = [
    OneHotEncoder(
     inputCol=c,
      outputCol="{0}_enc".format(c)) for c in cat_numeric]

label_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = "dep", outputCol = "label")

assembler = VectorAssembler(
 inputCols=[enc.getOutputCol() for enc in encoders1] +[enc.getOutputCol()    for enc in encoders2]+ con_columns,
outputCol="features")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexers + encoders1 +encoders2+[label_indexer]+[assembler])

model = pipeline.fit(final_df)
```